# MySQL select all rows in one tables matching unique values in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. Both contain 1 column with same value. I need to select all rows of one table if they have same value in another table.

How can do it?

Comment: Use INNER JOIN.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2
WHERE column.table_1 = column.table_2
```

This will return all the values that are in both table 1 and table 2 where the value in the column in table 1 is also in table 2